# How to retrieve user "basic profile" and email information for Google authenticated user

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm working on a simple Google login integration for a website. I need a user to be able to click a button, authenticate with Google, and then retrieve some basic information - name, ID, and email address. I'm using PHP for this task as it's my only real option for the site.

I've been trying to use the beta PHP API found [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/src/Google) and for the most part have gotten it to work by employing the example laid out [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app). The example tries to get user authorization for the application to access Drive file meta data, so I needed to change the scope to be more appropriate for the information we need. I made the following adjustment and it appeared to work fine:

Out:

`$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);`

In:

`$client->addScope("email");`

After authenticating with Google I'm prompted to authorize the application for both basic profile information and email access. The problem I have now is getting the application to actually retrieve the information it has been authorized to access. I haven't been able to locate an example similar to my scenario, using the version of the PHP API I'm using or the example that Google itself provides.

Essentially I need to replace this:

```
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
echo json_encode($files_list);
```

With commands that can grab the name, ID, and email of the user that's authenticated with Google via our app.

**Edit:** Received answer below. Had to make some small edits to get it to work just right.

`$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);` [Added 'new' before Google_Service_Oauth2]

`print_r($google_oauthV2->userinfo->get());` [Didn't like dump(), changed it to print_r to blast out the results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from digging around the source code, I found [Github - Google_Service_Oauth2.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php)

```
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$google_oauthV2 = Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
dump($google_oauthV2->userinfo->get());
```

Comment: Thanks! Dropped this in my code and tweaked it a bit and it worked like a charm.